# What is format of this file?

Tags: python, xml, file, file-format, formats

I have a file like this:

```
+----[ Stream 0 ]
|
| Type: Video
| Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (h264)
| Original ID: 1030
|
+----[ IRIB TV3 [Program 103] ]
|
| Status: Running
| Type: Digital television service
| Now Playing: میان برنامه
| Publisher: IRIB
|
+----[ EPG IRIB TV3 [Program 103] ]
|
| 2014-08-03 14:42:00:Hello
|
+----[ Stream 1 ]
|
| Type: Audio
| Codec: MPEG AAC Audio (mp4a)
| Original ID: 1031
|
+----[ end of stream info ]
```

What is format of this file , Is there any simple way to convert it to XML?

Comment: Sure, just wrap the whole thing in a `CDATA`. Or did you have some particular XML format you wanted? If so, what's the schema? Do you have something in particular you want to be able to search or xls or whatever, or do you just want some "store any generic hierarchy of strings" schema like plist?

Comment: No, I want particular XML format,Like plist.

Comment: It would be helpful if you actually told us what that format is.

Comment: Where did you get this file? It seems like some EPG or PSI but its not in a format I recognize.

Comment: It's EPG info from IRIB TV3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language you use for parsing this file is up to you, and depends what you are familiar with. Many people would use Perl, but I would use XSLT 2.0.

I would start by doing it line-by-line: there's a small number of different patterns to the lines, and I would translate

```
+----[ Stream 0 ]
```

to

```
<Stream>0</Stream>
```

and

```
Status: Running
```

to

```
<Status>Running</Status>
```

That would give you something that's XML, and phase 2 is to convert it into useful XML, which you can do using the grouping facilites in XSLT 2.0 to create something like

```
<Report>
  <Stream nr="0">
    <Type>Video</Type>
    ...
    <Program nr="103">
      <Status>Running</Status>
      ...
    </Program>
  </Stream>
  <Stream>...
</Report>
```

But there's no magic bullet here; unless someone has already produced code you can re-use, you're going to have to write a parser for this stuff.